# How do you find the underlying class behind a Laravel facade?

Tags: php, laravel

For example - this function uses a facade:

```
File::get('path/to/file.txt');
```

It turns out the underlying class that actually supplies `File::get` is `Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem`

I looked at the Laravel 4.2 documentation - thats the version Im using - and also the api reference but I couldn't find anything that would explain how to someone who didn't *know in advance* how to find the "real" class to a facade.

this [tutorial on Laravel facades](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=video&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCAQtwIwAQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DKXuMy1ejZVU&ei=uCY0VeyoIdXe8AXjuYGwDw&usg=AFQjCNEewIO_0bHtpL7yfVrxtFz7h9uMag&sig2=MxunGNestT2_5ufQl3O3Gg&bvm=bv.91071109,d.dGY) gives a method of doing it which involves

- finding the `File` class
- looking to see that it extends class `Facade`
- following the code through the `Facade#__callstatic()` method
- tracing the behaviour of `__callstatic()`, `resolveFacadeInstance()` when `getFacadeAccessor()` returns string `files`
- etc, etc
- ... too long / many steps to post

This is a good demonstration of whats going on, but I wouldn't want to do this regularly.

My question is, knowing that the "facaded classes" you use in your app dont necessarily have a the same name or some convention to help you search the filesystem,  how can someone - who doesn't know in advance what the underlying class is - find the underlying class for a laravel facade?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a nice resource: https://laravel.com/docs/facades#facade-class-reference other than that make sure to install some kind of intellisense plugin for whatever editor you happen to be using. Most of them allow you to Ctrl+Right-Click on a class/method and go to the definition.

Comment: This is very good article that explains story behind Laravel facades http://seregazhuk.github.io/2016/05/27/laravel-facades/

Answer (score 10):

It seems that you can use `getFacadeRoot()`. For example, to find out what's behind the `Mail` facade:

```
get_class(Mail::getFacadeRoot());
// in my case returns 'Illuminate\Mail\Mailer'
```